# Use curved voltage arrows for voltage source in circuitikz

Tags: tikz-styles, circuitikz

I would like to use curved arrows for the voltage source when using the `circuitikz` package.
For example, using

```
    \begin{circuitikz}[european voltages]
    \draw (0,0) to[R, v^=$v_1$] (2,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
```

and

```
    \begin{circuitikz}[european voltages]
    \draw (0,0) to[V=10V, i_=$i_1$] (2,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
```

one obtains the following symbols:

[image]
[image]

How could I use the voltage arrow style from the first case on the source in the second case? That is: I want a curved voltage arrow for the source. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.  It's much easier to help if we can start with something that will compile at this end.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the voltage arrow for voltage source is straight. One way to get the arrow is to draw it manually.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
   \begin{circuitikz}[european voltages]
    \draw (0,0) to[V,l=10V, i_=$i_1$] (2,0);
    \draw (0.35,0.1) .. controls (0.7,0.7)  and (1.3,0.7) ..node[currarrow, sloped,  allow upside down, pos=1] {} (1.65,0.1);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: *This might not be a good option when you have to do this multiple times.*